# Inner Html and why is this code not working?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i put an alert box in to see if the code worked but when I ran it the code did not work. I tried debugging it and I think the issue is on document.getelementbyid (ofbat) but not sure exactly what is wrong there. 
Also once the code works how do i add inner html to it so the answer comes out on the same screen? I emphasized the part where i thought the code was not working.

```
<html !doctype>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Lab7 Baseball Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculation() {

        var batterName = parseFloat(document.getElementById('battername').value);
        *var atBat = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('ofbat').value);*
        var ofSingles = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('ofsingles').value);
        var ofDoubles = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('ofdoubles').value);
        var ofTriples = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('oftriples').value);
        var ofHome = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('ofhome').value);
        var totalBases = ofSingles *1 + ofDoubles * 2 + ofTriples * 3 + ofHome *4;
        var slugPercent =totalBases/ atBat;
            alert batterName + slugPercent;
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Slugging Percentage Calculator</h1>
    <form>
        <p>Batter's Name:</p> 
        <input type="text" id="battername" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of At Bats:</p>
        <input type="text" id="ofbat" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of Singles:</p>
        <input type="text" id="ofsingles" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of Doubles:</p>
        <input type="text" id="ofdoubles" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of Triples:</p>
        <input type="text" id="oftriples" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of Home Runs:</p>
        <input type="text" id="ofhome" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Whats his slugging percentage?" onclick="calculation()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you doing checks to ensure that `atBat` is non-zero, a required field, and is a valid number?

Comment: I am not sure what you exactly mean. When I do the input I do enter a real number but if u are referring to how it is in the code I am not sure on how to make it a required field and how to accept only valid numbers

Comment: What is your specific question? What is the code supposed to do? What is it doing now? Saying "it doesn't work" isn't very helpful. Do you get any errors? Did you look in your developer console? What line(s) are the issue? Why do you believe that you need to use `.innerHTML`?

Comment: The code is supposed to take the batters name the amount of singles,doubles,triples and home runs they have hit and calculate the sluggers percentage .The formula for slugging percentage is  
• Slugging Percentage  = Total Bases ÷ At Bats, and  • Total Bases = Singles + (2 x Doubles) + (3 x Triples) + (4 x Home Runs). I want to use innerhtml instead of alertbox to provide the answer below the form. I did run developer console and I emphasized the part where I thought the code had an error in the above post.

Comment: Fix all your calls to parseFloat. `ofHome = parseFloat(document.getElementById)('ofhome').value);`   [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is the getElementById method syntax.

Comment: `.innerHTML` is not really the best or advised approach and should definitely not be used when you are not setting/getting any text with HTML in it. Instead, set the `.textContent` of a pre-existing elmeent to the final result.

Comment: But you have syntax errors in your code. If you did look at the Console, didn't you see it telling you that and where the errors were?

Comment: @ScottMarcus what if I wanted it to say : Scott Marcus slugging percentage is .... ? Would it not be proper to use innerhtml for that?

Comment: `someElement.textContent = "Scott Marcus slugging percentage is " + slugPercent;` There's no HTML in this string, so you don't use `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors:

1. `document.getElementById)('ofbat')`: `)` after `Id`. Same with all next lines.
2. `alert` is also a function so it should be called as `alert(argument)`

I think I found all syntax errors, if not let me know:

```
<html !doctype>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Lab7 Baseball Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculation() {
        var batterName = parseFloat(document.getElementById('battername').value);
        var atBat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ofbat').value);
        var ofSingles = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ofsingles').value);
        var ofDoubles = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ofdoubles').value);
        var ofTriples = parseFloat(document.getElementById('oftriples').value);
        var ofHome = parseFloat(document.getElementById('ofhome').value);
        var totalBases = ofSingles * 1 + ofDoubles * 2 + ofTriples * 3 + ofHome * 4;
        var slugPercent = totalBases / atBat;
            alert(batterName + slugPercent);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Slugging Percentage Calculator</h1>
    <form>
        <p>Batter's Name:</p> 
        <input type="text" id="battername" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of At Bats:</p>
        <input type="text" id="ofbat" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of Singles:</p>
        <input type="text" id="ofsingles" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of Doubles:</p>
        <input type="text" id="ofdoubles" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of Triples:</p>
        <input type="text" id="oftriples" /><br />
        <p>Enter number of Home Runs:</p>
        <input type="text" id="ofhome" /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Whats his slugging percentage?" onclick="calculation()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

UPD: edited code some number of times because found one more syntax error. If you haven't seen this line, please check the code again.

Comment: It says NAN when I run it. Also how can i just do innerhtml so it shows up on the screen itself instead of doing an alertbox?

Comment: @hello711 It would be better if you explain what output for some sample input you want to get. For example I can't understand if `parseFloat(document.getElementById('battername').value)` is correct, because if you want to write number there, then everything is ok, but if string is provided, then it will fail with NaN.